# GTKMM3 related error while installing Cadabra on Windows

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm, vcpkg

I'm trying to install [Cadabra](https://cadabra.science/) on Windows. Following the [instructions](https://github.com/kpeeters/cadabra2#windows), I inevitably get stuck near the very end, after cloning the repository and whilst using *cmake*. The error I am met with is:

```
CMake Error at cmake/windows.cmake:194 (message):
Could NOT find library gdkmm required for GTKMM3_LIBRARIES
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/modules/FindGTKMM3.cmake:3 (windows_find_library)
C:/Users/user/code/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:772 (_find_package)
frontend/CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
```

Previously, I've had the *exact same* error pop up for two other libraries, *atkmm* and *gdk*, but solved these two by typing the following into the terminal:

```
vcpkg install atkmm:x64-windows
install gtk3:x64-windows
```

respectively. (The first one might be redundant, I am not sure.)
This caveman-mentality approach to solving the issue came directly from the directions themselves, as one of the previous steps utilizes `vcpkg install gtkmm:x64-windows`, which should (I guess?) install everything necessary, but it doesn't seem to do so.

My question, then, is how can I download/install/build ***gdkmm*** on my Windows OS?

I have tried using similar commands like:

```
vcpkg install gdkmm:x64-windows
```

but what I'm met with is another error, stating that this does not exist. My guess is that all of the above were somehow and somewhere located in my *vcpkg* folder locally, whereas the one from above is missing.